# laravel $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am getting below error in Laravel Angularjs Application

> Error: Expecting a token named "token" but instead got: "\n**Deprecated**: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is
>   deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this
>   warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use
>   the php://input stream instead. in **Unknown** on line **0**\n
> \n**Warning**: Cannot modify header information - headers
>   already sent in **Unknown** on line **0**
> \n

i changed `'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1'` this into **0,1** also command still same error how to fix that

Comment: What PHP is this? And what Laravel is this?

Comment: PHP 5.6.31 & Laravel 5.1.46